# How to select related columns by having just an id number?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
// mytable
+----+---------+
| id | related |
+----+---------+
| 1  | 1       |
| 2  | 1       |
| 3  | 2       |
| 4  | 1       |
| 5  | 3       |
| 6  | 2       |
| 7  | 4       |
| 8  | 4       |
| 9  | 2       |
+----+---------+
```

I have just an id number like `$id = 6`. And I want to select all rows which have identical `related`. So this is expected result:

```
// newmytable
+----+---------+
| id | related |
+----+---------+
| 3  | 2       |
| 6  | 2       |
| 9  | 2       |
+----+---------+
```

How can I do that?

Here is my query but doesn't work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable m 
WHERE (SELECT related 
             FROM mytable 
             WHERE id = :id) t m.related = t.related
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select m2.id, m2.related
from 
mytable m1
join mytable m2
on m2.related = m1.related 
where m1.id = 6
```

[**SQL Fiddle sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf5f1/1/0)

Comment: Also can I use `m1` for selecting right?  like this `m1.id, m1.related`

Comment: Also why not `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: You cannot use m1.id because m1.id will be always equal to 6. The LEFT JOIN doesn't make sense here as you join to the same table. The LEFT JOIN = JOIN for the case.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE related = (SELECT releated FROM mytable WHERE id = 6)
```

Comment: There isn't any row which has `related = 6`. `6` is the an id number.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE related = ( SELECT related FROM mytable WHERE id = 6)
```

Not tested...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select *from mytable 
where related = (select related from mytable where id = 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello please replace your query with below query you will get your expected output.

SELECT * FROM mytable  WHERE = (SELECT related FROM mytable WHERE id = :id)